# rsync: how to exclude the topmost directory

Tags: rsync

So, I have a seemingly simple issue, but so far I haven't found a solution: I want to exclude the topmost directory from an rsync, while still syncing all its children. The particular issue is that I don't have permission to modify the times of the topmost directory, but want all the children to have properly sync'd times.

The rsync command I'm using is as follows:

```
rsync --exclude ./ -rlptDu ./ server.example.com:/usr/local/directory/
```

and `server.example.com:/usr/local/directory/` looks like this:

```
drwxrws---  5 root   staff 24576 Jul  9 15:00 .
```

(my local user is a member of `staff`)

When I run rsync, I get the following error:

```
rsync: failed to set times on "/usr/local/directory/.": Operation not permitted (1)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1070) [sender=3.0.9]
make: *** [pub_to_mel_internal] Error 23
```

This is version 3.0.9 on the local machine and 3.0.7 on the remote, both machines running Debian.

Comment: Are you familiar with the syntax in this example: http://wirespeed.xs4all.nl/mediawiki/index.php/Dirvish_include_single_directory_or_folder It allows you to include specific files/directories from an otherwise excluded directory. You might need to use an exclude file though.

Comment: Yeah. The issue is that I can't seem to convince it to exclude the toplevel directory (specifically). I haven't had issues with mixing includes / excludes in the past, it just seems as though the toplevel is a special case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think rsync's filter rules can't match the toplevel directory, so it's always synchronized. A workaround is to synchronize all the files inside this directory instead of the directory itself.

```
rsync -rlptDu -- * server.example.com:/usr/local/directory/
```

Add `.[!.]*` after `*` if you have dot files in the topmost directory, and `..?*` if you have file names beginning with two dots.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That works. The only downside of this technique is that it requires the shell to select all the files. If you have tons of files in the directory (which I don't in my case), it may choke. That could probably be fixed using xargs (although not with the --delete options).

Comment: One problem I got with using `*` was that `--delete` did not delete any files, since they were not part of the search.

Comment: @thomasa88 Please see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1464297/432690).

Answer (score 1):

It seems rsync can exclude the topmost directory using `--files-from`:

```
$ rsync -anv from/ to/
sending incremental file list
./
a
b.test

sent 97 bytes  received 25 bytes  244.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
$ printf '%s\n' 'a' 'b.test' | rsync -anv --files-from=- from/ to/
building file list ... done
a
b.test

sent 88 bytes  received 22 bytes  220.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

Just stumbled upon it, leaving a clue here in case it helps someone (or me in the future).